Why is there a difference in Confusion Matrix Metrics between Azure Custom Vision Portal & implementation of the same using Python SDK in Jupyter?
Ive been using the custom vision api for object detection purposes, currently im using an object detection model with Products on Shelves as the domain. Im doing this implementation (starting from creating a project) to annotation to uploading the preprocessed images along with their annotations to training & evaluating the model via python sdk in jupyter notebook.
Parallelly I am keeping a watch on the vision portal to ensure what im implementing is reflecting in vision studio. After training my model, i check the performance metrics using the following code(along with values, please find the image below)
Snippet of code + results in Jupyter
I didnt tweak the probability or the overlap threshold, checked on the portal after training(no prediction yet), here are the values displayed
Portal shows different values for Confusion Matrix
Can any one help me understand why is there a difference in metrics? I havent done any prediction, just annotated the same in local, uploaded them, checked on portal they were the same, then trained using python sdk and printed the metrics, checked on the portal (iteration id was also the same) but results are different ?
Here is the link of question I have asked on the Microsoft help portal as well !
Thank You
I have tried checking the iteration id, if im using the correct one or not. Also i noticed when i did quick test using the python sdk and got probability score predictions, there was a slight difference in what was in my jupyter and what was displayed under prediction tab in portal

Please include code and outputs as formatted code text rather than images.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

please verify:

you are using the same dataset in both cases (train/test, ...)
Compare the preprocessing steps applied
Use the same model version

please provide more code to understand better the issue
